# Button in BottomNavgationView doesn't work properly

Tags: android, scroll, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I have a `BottomNavigationView` with 3 buttons/items. The middle one makes my 3 `NestedScrollView` (each one in each fragment of a `viewpager`) scroll to the top of the view. Until here everything is ok. The problem beggins when I check all the three, because suddenly the button stops react. I tryed the debuggin and it passes all the steps... I don't know what the problem is, can you help me? Here's the code:

```
private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.lista_utentes -> {
            onBackPressed()
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }

        R.id.topo -> {
            when (viewpager_tabs_tipo.currentItem) {
                0 -> container_feridas.scrollTo(0, 0)
                1 -> container_sinais.scrollTo(0, 0)
                2 -> container_analises.scrollTo(0, 0)
            }

        }
        R.id.new_foto -> {
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
    }
    false
}
```

Comment: why not using the 'setUserVisibleHint' method in each fragment and scroll in there?

Comment: Hi @Raykud I think that will bring more code or you are thinkin' better than me. To do that I would have to put BottomNavigation in each fragment_layout and create 3 similiar function... What you think?

Comment: no, on each fragment you will only have to override that setUserVisibleHint method and put the 'scrollTo' call as the scrolls are in the fragment already.. that setUserVisibleHint method gets called when the fragment gets visible to the user.

Comment: @Raykud Ok, and then what i put next to " R.id.topo -> {". I'm sorry, I'm confused now.

Comment: Hi @Raykud I've tried to call setUserVisibleHint inside R.id.topo, but nothing worked. There is another way to call it? Thank you.